# X-Frame-Options deny?

Tags: jquery, .net, x-frame-options

I load a "page" trought jQuery $.getJSON (for some reasons, all the page is coded as JSON; then I decode it when the function has been succes), which contain an iframe that point to another source!
All the code come from .NET 4.0.

When I open the page on Firefox, on console I get `Load denied by X-Frame-Options`.
On chrome I don't have any troubles.

How can I fix this problem? Where am I wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)